# Javascript regular expression to ignore a sequence of full-stops/dots

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to count the number of words in a string in javascript but ignore words that contain the characters "..." anywhere in the string.  I know that a "." can function as a special character in a regular expression but my attempts to break it below aren't working (4th line of the function)...

```
function countWords(s){
        s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");//exclude  start and end white-space
        s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");//2 or more space to 1
        s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n"); // exclude newline with a start spacing
        s = s.replace(/\.\.\.$/,""); //exclude words ending in ...  
        return s.split(' ').length; 
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `$` that is matching thr `...` only at the end of the string. Try removing `$`. Or `/\b\.{3}/`,

Comment: thanks stribizhev - that's a good point, but I should have said that I was starting out by testing this on a ... sequence at the end of the string only - so it still doesn't successfully ignore "string..."

Comment: And what about `\b\.{3}`? It will match triple dots after any word in the string.

Comment: nope - this line doesn't work either "s = s.replace(/\b\.{3}$/,"");"  i.e. I pass the string "Test String ..." to the function and I get a count of 3.  And I pass the string "Test String..." and I get a count of 2.

Comment: `…` is also actually a character. It's called horizontal ellipsis. `&#133` or `&hellip;` http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Why are you using `$`? `$` makes the regex match at the end of string. `s = s.replace(/\b(?:\.{3}|\u2026)/g,"")`. `\u2026` is the ellipsis symbol.

Comment: Sorry but using "s = s.replace(/\b\.{3}/g,"");" in the function has the same result as described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select your words ending in "..." or " ..."

```
/\w+\s*[\.]{3}/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/uZ4cH9/1

Like 'String...' or 'String ...' on the cases above..

> Test String...
>
> Test String ...

---

Now if do you want only select the first 'String' you should use this:

```
/\w+[\.]{3}/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/yF2vV2/1

---

Improved version, deals with other special characters:

```
/\S+[\.]{3}/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/xI4rM8/1

Comment: Thanks Mayo - I'm seeing that case 1 "Test String..." works perfectly and returns a count of 1.  But case 2 "Test String ..." also returns a count of 1 (despite the whitespace between "String" and "...").  Does it work differently for you?

Comment: Oh, I thought that you wanted to ignore the space after. So, do you want to count (in the second line) Test and String, right ?

Comment: Ahh sorry about that - yes, I want to completely ignore ... from the word count - meaning that if a "..." appears in isolation (i.e. separated by whitespace) it's ignored from the count, and if a "..." touches another word, then the word it touches (plus the "...") are ignored from the count.  Apologies again if my post wasn't clear on that

Comment: But as I mentioned to Casimir, ideally words could be defined by whitespace boundaries?  Otherwise apostrophes, numbers etc will boost the word count unnecessarily.

Comment: mmm, givme a sec.. do you have a text sample?

Comment: Of course, here's a few: "Test string..." should return 1.  "Test string ..." should return 2.  "Test's ..." should return 1.  "Test's string..." should return 1. "John's 3..." should return 1.  "John's 3 ..." should return 2.  Thanks again for any thoughts at all!

Comment: Ok what about this one: https://regex101.com/r/xI4rM8/1 I changed the \w by \S (non space character)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
function countWords(s) {
    return s.split(/\b(?:\w+(?:\.{3}|\u2026)|\W+)/).filter(Boolean).length;
}
```

Instead of using several replacements, this function split the string at non-words characters or at a word followed by 3 dots (or the ellipsis character). `filter(Boolean)` removes empty items.

Note that what I call "word" is one or more characters from `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, if your definition of a word is different, please explain what you are exactly looking for in your question.

If you want to count as one word, words separated by apostrophe or hypen, then it is more easy to use the `match` method:

```
return s.match(/\w+(?:['-]\w+)*\b(?!\.{3}|\u2026)/g).filter(Boolean).length;
```

In this way you can precisely describe what is allowed or not.

Comment: Thanks Casimir - this works perfectly based on my question so I've accepted the answer.  As you mention though, if my words include things like an apostrophe or number, it will alter the count (e.g. "Teststring 3..." returns a count of 2, and "Jason's..." returns a count of 1) - do you know if it’s possible to adapt this to use whitespace as a definition of a word boundary?

Comment: @d3wannabe: yes, but in this case it is more easy to use the `match` method. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> ignore words that contain the characters "..." anywhere in the string

...

> s.replace(/...$/,""); //exclude words ending in ...

This regex only replaces '...' when it occurs at the end of the string, not anywhere.

To avoid joining up words seperated by '...' (or even just .):

```
function countWords(s){
    s = s.replace(/\./g," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n/," "); 
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/g," ");//2 or more space to 1
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");//exclude  start and end white-space
    return s.split(' ').length; 
}
```

Comment: thanks symcbean, although as I just mentioned in my comments to stribizhev, my original regular expression "s = s.replace(/\.\.\.$/,"")" wasn't even removing ... at the end of the string.

Comment: How do you know it wasn't removing the string - you don't say what behaviour you observed and you've shown us no code which determine if '...' was removed or not. There was indeed a small bug in my code now fixed by moving the trim leading/trailing whitespace to the after the replacements, but this would only overcount the number of words when there is a trailing ...

Comment: I know it wasn't removing it because I'm calling the function countWords with sample text and outputting the results to console.  Your latest version "s = s.replace(/\./g," ");" successfully counts "String test ..." as 2 words, but also counts as "String te..." as 2 words.  Any ideas how to eliminate that latter case?

Answer (score 0):

try using 
s.replace(/\w*\.\.\.(\B|\b)\w*/,"");

instead of

s.replace(/\.\.\.$/,"");

This will work only for word containing only one ... sub-string. For, more you need to modify this

Comment: you mean a last line of "s = s.replace(/:: \.\.\.(\B|\b)/,"");" - that has the same result too - "String test ..." returns a count of 3 words, and "String test..." returns a count of 2

Answer (score 0):

```
    function count_words()
    {
    str1= document.getElementById("InputText").value;

//exclude  start and end white-space   
    str1 = str1.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");

//convert 2 or more spaces to 1      
    str1 = str1.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");

 // exclude newline with a start spacing  
    str1 = str1.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    document.getElementById("noofwords").value = str1.split(' ').length;
    }
```

Try this it works for me

Comment: thanks Donika, but which line ignores the ... sequence?  (Sorry if I'm missing something!)